# Want to find the amount generated by a single event in one month followed by several events

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join, window-functions

I want to find the revenue generated by a particular event.
If I would say, event1 pitched on 8/1/2020 to customers A and B, event 2 pitched on 8/15/2020 to customer B & C, event 3 pitched on 8/30/2020. Then to find the revenue generated by event1, we need to find A customer and B customer pitched again for that month or not. If yes then consider the transaction date just before the date when the customer is pitched again. In the given example, A customer pitched again on 08/30/2020 and B customer pitched on 8/15/2020then then to calculate for event1 we need to consider the transaction of customer A till 8/29/2020 from the 8/1/2020 and Customer B till 8/14/2020 from the 8/1/2020.

Event Table:

```
EventID  CID  Date
123      1    01-12-2020
123      2    01-12-2020
123      3    01-12-2020
345      2    05-12-2020
345      4    05-12-2020
456      1    07-12-2020
456      4    07-12-2020
567      1    08-12-2020
```

Transaction Table:

```
UID Tran_Date   Amount
 1   03-12-2020  10
 1   04-12-2020  20
 1   07-12-2020  30
 1   09-12-2020  40
 2   03-12-2020  10
 2   07-12-2020  30
 2   07-12-2020  40
 2   09-12-2020  30
 3   07-12-2020  30
 3   07-12-2020  40
 3   09-12-2020  30
```

Output Table:

```
EventID  CID  Sum
 123      1    30
 456      1    30
 567      1    40
 123      2    10
 456      2    100
 123      3    100
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: @gmb 
Yes, I tried. For a few users ID, it's giving correct results. However, there is one problem with this. For UID 2, two times event occurred one is on 01-12-2020 for an Event ID 123 and another is on 05-12-2020 for an Event ID 345. It's giving accurate transaction amount for an Event 123 i.e. 10 in output. But for an Event ID 345, it's giving 0 as output. However, UID 2 also transacts on the following date i.e. on 07-12-2020 and 09-12-2020, the total transaction done by UID 2 for that event is 100.
Likewise for UID 1 for an Event ID 567 and UID 3 for an Event ID 123 inaccurate

Answer (score 0):

One option uses window function `lead()` to get the date of the "next" event, then brings the transactions with a join, and finally aggregates:

```
select
    e.eventid,
    e.cid,
    coalesce(sum(t.amount), 0) total_amount
from (
    select e.*, lead(date) over(partition by cid order by date) lead_date
    from events e
) e
left join transactions t 
    on  t.uid = e.cid
    and t.tran_date >= e.date
    and (t.tran_date < e.lead_date or e.lead_date is null)
group by e.eventid, e.cid
```

Note that window functions are available in MySQL 8.0 only. In earlier versions, you can emulate `lead()` with a correlated subquery.

Comment: No doubt query is working, however, results are not as expected. There is no transaction that happened for UID  456 but it's still giving a transaction value for the same UID. lly for CID 1, only one time the customer did the transaction from the date of event ID 567 i.e on 09-12-2020 which of 40 but in the given output, it's giving 310 as output.
Event ID 345 /CID 2 and Event ID 123, and CID 3 inaccurate

What I want if the system does find any transaction from the execution of the last event for particular UID then it considers transaction for that day or after that day of the event.

Comment: Yeah working fine. Thanks for all the thoughts and your efforts.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff No doubt its working fine. However, where I want to run this query at another user end who is using Version 5 is not support this as you mentioned. So if you could help me how we can achieve without the lead() function then it would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sid . . . This answers the question you have asked here.  If you have a different question -- say due to a different version of MySQL -- then ask a new question.